# Conditional component in Svelte not rendering CSS

Tags: css, typescript, vite, svelte

A generalized layout of my application is below, it's a directory where upon click of a person the directory goes away and displays more details on that person with a "close" button that reverts back to the directory. Functionality works fine.

**App.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
//// import component ////
//// api fetch for directory ///
//// api fetch for details ///
</script>

{#if !details}
/// display directory ///
<a 
on:click( // do a function to fetch details of person and set details as true //) 
> person </a>
{/#if}

{#if details}
<div class="profile_overlay">
<DetailsBox {details} {closebtn} />
</div>
{/#if}

<style>

//// all of the styling for the directory, that's plainly programmed within app.svelte works and renders find, putting any of the details styling here does not work ////

    // test 1) this does not work, the browser just uses default H1 styling
        .profile_overlay .details__Name {
            color: red
        }

    // test 3) this does not work, the browser just uses default H1 styling
        .profile_overlay :global(.details__Name) {
            color: red
        }

    // test 4) this does not work, the browser just uses default H1 styling
        .profile_overlay :global(h1) {
            color: red
        }

</style>
```

**DetailsBox.svelte**

```
<script>
    export let details = {}; //pull in api fetch from app.svelte
    export let closeDetails; //pull in closedetails function
</script>  

<svelte:options tag="details-component" />
<h1 class="details__Name">{details.FirstName} {details.LastName}</h1>


<style>
    // test 2) this does not work, the browser just uses default H1 styling
        .details__Name {
            color: red
        }
</style>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm not understanding about Svelte component styling? I did also notice that when the styling is only in DetailsBox.svelte it's not grabbed into the application's styling upon build.